# how to restrict logins in firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, web, firebase-security

Lets say I have 2 platforms, android and web, linked to my database.

The android is for the users to access while the web is for the admins to access. Both web and android shows different information.

How can I prevent the users from logging in to the web and the admins from the app?

Extra info -the users information are store in /users/uid(firebase generated).
While the admins information are not stored in the database.

Comment: Very simple, you need to verify each user if is an admin or not. If is an admin let him log-in trough web, and restrict android and vice versa. Hope it helps.

Comment: By verify, do you mean using firebase rules to do it? If so I assume it wouldnt work because the rules will apply to both web and android. So if i set it such that if user are not admin they wouldnt be able to login, it will affect the android part too. Which will cause them to be unable to login through android.

Or do  you mean using a if else statement. If so, the admin details are not stored in database so how am i suppose to set a condition for the web to make sure its admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can not restrict login like that.

### Web

On successful login, check whether the user is ADMIN or not. If ADMIN allow access to content, otherwise redirect to a error page which shows "RESTRICTED ACCESS"

### Android

You can do the vice versa. On successful login, if ADMIN restrict the access.

To protect data at the database level, you have to do in firebase database rules.

Your DB Structure should be as follows:

```
|
 --admins: ['Add admin emails here as an array'],
|
 --adminContent: Put admin content here,
|
 --userContent: Put user content here
```

Your database rules should be:

```
"adminContent": {
    ".read": "root.child('admins').val().contains(auth.email)",
    ".write": "root.child('admins').val().contains(auth.email)"
}
"userContent": {
    ".read": "!root.child('admins').val().contains(auth.email)",
    ".write": "!root.child('admins').val().contains(auth.email)"
}
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. Regarding your solution, wouldn't it just prevent the users from accessing the data?  They can still log in both platforms except that they can't retrieve the data. correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Oh sorry.  I think I get it now. I will try it out and give you an answer asap if it works.